# What overhead is caused by echo + fread-ing a file for download?

Tags: php, file

If I have a php script that does nothing but the following...

```
$file = fopen($path, "r");
flock($file, LOCK_SH);

echo fread($file, filesize($path));

flock($file, LOCK_UN);
fclose($file);
```

...how much overhead is caused by accessing the script from a browser as opposed to simply accessing the actual file? Internally, is the entire file copied to some kind of buffer and then spit out again or is it nearly the same thing?

Comment: About as much memory as loading the entire file into memory will take; why not just use [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) instead, as it has no memory overhead?

Comment: @MarkBaker Well... cause I didn't know about it. Heh. Thanks, I'll use that for now. I don't think it will work in the future though, as I'll only be outputting the second half of the file. Is there a way to move the file pointer to a designated starting point before calling readfile()?

Comment: You could probably stream only a partial file using readfile() using a context

Comment: @MarkBaker Aite, I'll look into it. Thanks man.

Comment: Take a look at `fpassthru()`. It's like `readfile()` but it takes a file handle instead of filename. So you can first seek to the middle of the file, then call `fpasthru()` to send the rest to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's read into a buffer. It's essentially equivalent to:

```
$temp = fread($file, filesize($path));
echo $temp;
```

You can use `fpassthru()` to send to the client without reading everything into a buffer at once.

```
fpassthru($file);
```

Comment: Great! And just for knowledge, what if I wanted to pluck the middle out of a file? It seems that fpassthru reads until EOF.